# Could someone explain a step in this proof please

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Let $u(z)$ be a continuous function in the disc $|z-z_0|<r$ and let $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ be the circle $|z-z_0|=\epsilon$. Prove, $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{u(z)}{z-z_0} dz=u(z_0)$$

Using the theorem,

$$\int_{\gamma} u(z) dz= \int_{a}^{b} u(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) dt$$

The integral was simplified to,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it}) dt$$.

The next step confused me it was:

$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{u(z)}{z-z_0}~dz-u(z_0)\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{ 2\pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} (u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it})-u(z_0))~dt\right|\\&\leq \max_{0 \leq t \leq 2\pi} \left(u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it})-u(z_0)\right)\end{align}$$

The last quantity goes to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$ because $u(z)$ is continuous at $z_0$.

Please explain that step.

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up with the parenthesis, in the step

$$|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it})-u(z_0)dt| \leq max_{0 \leq t \leq 2\pi} (u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it})-u(z_0))$$

Observe that the term $u(z_0)$ is not inside the parenthesis of $u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it})$ and therefore $u(z_0+\epsilon e^{it}) \to u(z_0)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ and so the last quantity goes to $0$

Answer (score 0):

The equality is just algebra.

The inequality is an example of the more general fact that $\left|\int_C f(z)dz \right| \leq \operatorname{Length}(C) \operatorname{max}_{C} |f(z)|$.  Do you see why this inequality is true?